# How to reshape a 2x2 block matrix to mxm matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, reshape

I have a matrix M partitioned into blocks such that

[image]

where A is 25x25, B is 25x100, C is 100x25 and D is 100x100.

In Python, I have this matrix as an nparray which contains 4 arrays corresponding to each of A, B, C and D such that doing `M.shape` gives `(2,2)`. However, for purpose of calculation (inversion and multiplication, etc) I need it to have dimensions `(125,125)`. I've tired `M.reshape([125,125])` which doesn't work and gives the error `Cannot reshape (2,2) to (125,125)`. Is there a quick and easy way to do this, please?

Comment: What is supposed to go into the extra 123 elements in each dimension? will they be null or zero or one or will they contain data from the original 4?

Comment: @wwii Thanks for commenting. All the entries of the new matrix should be the elements of M. So essentially instead of having an array of arrays such as `array([[array([...]), array([...]), array([...]), array([...])]])` (which I have currently) I would like to have my matrix in the form `array([...])`. So I'm asking if there's a way to merge the nested arrays so that in the end I've got one array only. Currently, I am unable to perform operations such as matrix inversion and determinant of M as it is `dtype = object`.

Comment: `block` can join the arrays with one call.  Or you could do several `concatenate` steps.  `A,B` can be concatenate on axis 1,  Same for `C,D`,  Then join those two on axis  0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the NumPy [`block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy.block) function. Usage:

```
np.block([[a, b], [c, d]])
```

or in your case:

```
np.block(M)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the above doesn't work for me. Essentially, currently I've got something of form `array([[array([...]), array([...]), array([...]), array([...])]])` and I am looking for something of the for `array([...])` (with no nested arrays). So I'm basically asking if there's a way to merge the nested arrays so that in the end I've got one array only. Currently, I am unable to perform operations such as matrix inversion and determinant of M as it is dtype = object.

Comment: If your current object array is (1,4) shape, then `a,b,c,d=arr[0]` should set you up for using `block`.  Or `np.block([[arr[0,0], arr[0,1]],[arr[1,0],arr[1,1]]])`.  It is is (2,2) adjust the indexing.  Review the `block` docs.  For all practical purposes your current array is a list of 4 arrays.  Treat it as such.